# where is the graph file of open images pretrained model?

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I need the graph file(.pb file) of pretrained openimages dataset. After downloading the model there are only 3 files

```
labelmap.txt    
model.ckpt  
model.ckpt.meta
```

Where can I find the .pb file?

Answer (score 0):

The model.ckpt.meta contains both the graph and the weights. you have to import it using import_metagraph functionality.
Then you should be able to export the graph defn in pb format, if you really need it.
However I was unable to load the ckpt.meta, due to a google-specific op defined in the model. Please let me know if you can figure that out.